# Smart Phone Flash Tool Remain 0 percent

Tags: rom-flashing, device-firmware, flashtool, lenovo-a3000

I have a Lenovo A3000 tablet and I want to flash it (Reinstalling firmware?). So I download my tablet driver and MT65XX Preloader drivers for Windows. After installing all of them, when I click on `Download` button on in *Smart Phone Flash Tool* it successfully detect the COM port number, but it doesn't start to send data. Why?

P.S: I tried above steps with Win 7 32&64 bit, Win 8.1 64bit and Win XP!

[image]

Comment: Does the SPFT version you use support the device? Please check and report.

Comment: @TamoghnaChowdhury Based on this link : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fdPT6QBtEqw and the page that I downloaded it, yes. It support. Where is the report?

Comment: I meant check out and report back, not "report".

Comment: @TamoghnaChowdhury The problem was with the version of SPFT and the firmware! The firmware wasn't for my tablet and that version of SPFT  doesn't notify me that it is not for this device! When I installed the latest version of SPFT and retied the steps, in the last step, when I click on Download, it alert me that `Scattler` file version is not consistent with your Tablet. And I understood that my Tablet is A3300-GV (Not A3000)!!! Now, I am downloading the appropriate firmware. Thank you very much.

Comment: Please check out the answer, I compiled one from the comments

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<sub>Answer compiled from comments</sub>

The SPFT version you are using is probably incompatible with your device or firmware, and it is failing silently. Try downloading the latest version of SPFT and the correct firmware, and it should probably work.